# How do I retrieve account Id from the instance of a standard controller?

Tags: apex, visualforce

```
public class MyAccountClass
{
    //Class Constructor        
        public MyAccountClass(ApexPages.StandardController controller)
    {
        //Do Something
    }
}
```

Test class

```
@isTest
private class TestMyClass{
    @isTest
    private static void testClass()
    {
    //Standard controller of Account is just an example
    //Create a new instance of Account
    Account acc = new Account(Name = 'TestAccountName');

    //Insert the object virtually
    insert acc;

    //Create a new instance of standard controller
    ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.standardController(acc);

    MyAccountClass controller = new MyAccountClass(sc);
    // Fetch the account Id ?
    }
}
```

I am new to Visualforce, I have a class where I am using the ApexPages.StandardController to get the account Id and then I am using the Id in my class to fetch some values of an object that is associated to the account. I want to do the same in my test class to test if I am getting any values for the associated object but I am not getting the value of the account Id and I am always getting null. How do I fetch the value of account Id ?

Comment: Why try to get the ID from the controller, when you already have it in the "acc" instance you passed to the standard controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Id` field is always populated on an sObject when you perform DML, and it must be in the instance of the sObject you pass to the standard controller if that controller is to be able to access the record.

That's a long way of saying that you don't need to do anything with the standard controller to get access to that information because you already have it in the form of `acc.Id`.

Comment: I found out that I missed Insert. It's resolved.